# Buscar campo de MySQl creado en la misma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día.
Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select p.id_alumno as id,('estudiante') as tipo, p.url_imagen, concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
        e.nombre as empresa,concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante, p.fecha_alta, p.estado
        from estudiantes p inner join usuarios u on p.id_alumno = u.id_usuario 
                 inner join empresas e on u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa
```

y quiero aplicar este `where` dentro de la misma query:

```
where tipo like 'estudiante'.
```

Pero me dice que el  campo `tipo` no existe.

Como podría hacer para poder realizar dicha búsqueda, les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

PD: ya se que la consulta `where` devolverá siempre lo mismo, pero ocupo resolver este error para poder continuar en lo que estoy haciendo

Comment: No entiendo.. Que quieres hacer ? Puedes dar mas detalles para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar con `HAVING`

```
select p.id_alumno as id,('estudiante') as tipo, p.url_imagen, concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
        e.nombre as empresa,concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante, p.fecha_alta, p.estado
        from estudiantes p inner join usuarios u on p.id_alumno = u.id_usuario 
                 inner join empresas e on u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa HAVING tipo LIKE 'estudiante'
```

No olvidees los `%` en un LIKE, de lo contrario no tendría sentido usar like.

Más información de HAVING

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer poniendo el query en un sub-query y filtrarlo en el resultado:

```
select * from (
        -- ejecutas la consulta en un sub-query
        select  p.id_alumno as id,
        ('estudiante') as tipo, 
        p.url_imagen, 
        concat_ws(' ',p.nombre,p.paterno,p.materno) as nombre,
        e.nombre as empresa,
        concat_ws(' ',u.nombre,u.apellidos) as solicitante,
        p.fecha_alta, p.estado
            from estudiantes p 
                inner join usuarios u on p.id_alumno = u.id_usuario 
                inner join empresas e on u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa

) t
where t.tipo like 'estudiante'
```

Pero, porque quieres hacer un `like` aun valor constante? El valor de la columna `tipo` siempre sera el mismo por lo que no veo la necesidad de hacer la comparacion.